# Disconnecting (SSH) from Google Compute Engine stops the running API

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Any idea why when I connect remotely (ssh session) to my Google Compute Engine instance, if I run a command (run an HTTP API) and leave, this one stops running as well?

```
./main PORT // Stops when I leave
./main PORT & // Stops when I leave as well..
```

No matter what, if I disconnect from my current ssh session, my API stops, even if the engine still seems to run fine

Comment: That is expected behavior when you run a process like that in any shell. If the shell closes, so does the process it's running. Explain what you're trying to do so that we can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you disconnect your terminal, all processes started by that terminal are sent a "hangup" signal which, by default, causes the process to terminate.  You can trap the hangup signal when you launch a process at cause the signal to be silently ignored.  The easiest way to achieve this is with the nohup command.  For example:

```
nohup ./main PORT &
```

References:

- [What Is Nohup and How Do You Use It?](https://www.maketecheasier.com/nohup-and-uses/)
- [Unix Nohup: Run a Command or Shell-Script Even after You Logout](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/)
- [nohup(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)